# Is moment.js and moment.php the same?

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, momentjs

I have created a js script using moment.js and I want to replicate it through a cron job. So, it will be in PHP.

So, I searched for moment.js equivalents and I found this https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php

Comment: Hello, please read first the documentation https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to figure out how to ask a question. Once done, please edit your question to specify what you've done so far exactly and what is the issue preventing you to reach your goal

Comment: @Wisthler Okay, man. I'll edit later. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, they are *not* the same. The GitHub repo says:

> Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in PHP w/ i18n support. ***Inspired by moment.js***

I read "*inspired by*" as *similar in nature* or *close to*. Otherwise, it would say something like "PHP port of Moment.js" or "PHP wrapper around Moment.js".

---

You should define more clearly, however, what exactly you mean by "are they the same". Do you mean the API parity? Or API compatibility? Or something else?

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! I meant their functions.

Comment: @furtim Honestly, I don't know. If I were you, I would check the equivalence of each and every function that are used in the script you're porting. If you use many of them, that's not fun. But it's the only way IMO

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not the same as it says "Inspired by the javascript library moment.js" at below mentioned sources :

```
1) https://packagist.org/packages/lawondyss/moment-php
2) https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php
```

which means it is developed **by taking the reference of the javascript library moment.js** , it may contain the same functionality as well as it's own (newly added than the javascript moment.js).

You can compare the two from downloading/checking the documentation from different sources as below :

```
1) for moment.js you can check here : https://momentjs.com/
2) for moment.php you can check here : https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php OR 
   https://packagist.org/packages/lawondyss/moment-php
```